# Nivo Slider doesn't obey `width` command after setting position to absolute

Tags: nivo-slider

```
.slider-wrapper { 
    width: 80%; 

    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
```

I added the `position: absolute;` and `top: 200px;` to .slider-wrapper but the width of 80% isn't obeyed anymore after I added those two commands.

[Nivo Slider link](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Is your images getting wider or the div ?

Comment: My width became wider automatically as the `width:80%` is not obeyed anymore. I want it to obey the `width:80%` command.

Comment: What about the image is it obeying the width that you need? I am asking this because the nivo slider needs all images to be of same sized. If one is bigger it takes that width and height.

Comment: How do I find out if the image is obeying the `width:80%;` I set ?

Comment: Check your image size first and check the width you are specifying. Compare them and get a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set  `width: 80% !important;` ?